# No module named 'cv2' error in new environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have tried to rectify this issue by using

```
pip install opencv-python

pip install opencv-contrib-python

pip uninstall panda
pip install panda

conda install opencv-python
```

Some info is that im currently using python 3.6.10 and Windows 10.

```
opencv-python        4.2.0.32
numpy                1.18.1
panda                0.3.1
tensorflow-gpu       1.14.0
```

I created a new env but cant seem to import cv2 over on Jupyter Notebook. My earlier environment was able to do so. When i tried to pip install the opencv-python==4.1.2.30 (from the old environment's pip list), the problem was still there. Thank you for reading!

Comment: Is your jupyter notebook running on the same envirenment where you have installed opencv ?

Comment: Yes! I opened jupyter notebook in the cmd prompt, within the new environment.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check which pip you are using

```
which pip # for linux
where pip # for windows
```

If path is in your new enviroment then try to reinstall it else first set PATH of new enviroment pip to the terminal/command prompt.

Comment: It returns both Anaconda3\envs\Tracking\Scripts\pip.exe and
Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe. What do i do? Thank you!

Comment: whichever is first is the default right now. so if you want to use your env pip then set the path for it and install your package.

Answer (score 0):

I found the elementary mistake I made. I forgot to download jupyter notebook in my env. As a result, I think it brought me to the another directory which doesn't have opencv. Thank you pygirl and nitr_himanshu for your help!